# cant change url with rewrite module

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi guys i have bellow issue 
i try change my address something like this localhost/test.php?name=john to localhost/name/john.html so i used get method

index.php

```
 <?php
echo"<a href='register.php'>reg</a>";

echo<<<EOL
<form action="test.php" method="get">
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
EOL;
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
$jj=$_GET['name'];

echo "$jj";
?>
```

and my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

but still not working and im sure rewrite_module is on because in phpinfo in loadmodule can see rewrite
tnx

Comment: First of all, you translate the `.html` page to the wrong php page. Second of all, you are missing an external redirect.

Comment: sorry i forgot change my htaccess this is my htacess RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)\.html$ /test.php?name=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have an external redirect besides the internal rewrite, and you'll have to make sure that this doesn't result in an infinite loop. You can do this by using `%{THE_REQUEST}`, which will always be the same regardless of what you did rewrite the url to. You would end up with something like this:

```
#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)\.html$ /test.php?name=$1 [L]

#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /test\.php\?name=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^ /name/%2.html [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` after you have tested everything and you are sure it works as expected. 301-redirects, or permanent redirects, are sometimes cached by the browser and it is therefore an hell to test with them.

Comment: ty but still not wroking http://localhost/test.php?name=thjy i use ur htaccess and change that to R=301 but still same as past

Comment: I have changed the `THE_REQUEST` condition, since it should have been producing a redirect loop. Telling me that it still works "same as [before]" is not very helpful, considering that nor in the question, nor in the comments you have told what is happening in the first place.

Comment: Sry thats my wrong . i mean when i try change url nothing change same as before* url repeat again some thing like this  localhost/test.php?name=thjy but tnx to answering me

Comment: Assuming mod_rewrite is enabled, you have turned on mod rewrite with `RewriteEngine on` in .htaccess, the `FollowSymLinks` option is enabled and your .htaccess is in your document root this should work, even though I can't test it on this computer.

Comment: You are right about the `\?`. I don't think `&` has to be escaped?